# Chamisha Ve'esrim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred twenty-five?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reuvain, Dan, and Gad all lived 125 years

Answer (score 4):

There are exactly 125 days between Shavuos and Succos

Comment: Exclusive of both of them, you mean? (And that works only outside of Eretz Yisrael; in E.Y. it would be 126.)

Comment: So now you have something for 126.

Answer (score 3):

125 is majority of bones of one body which Beis Hillel require to make up the quarter of a kav of bones in order to make an ohel tamei. (Eiduyos 1:7)